# Javascript background event handling loop

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, frontend, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript so probably my question might look somehow primitive.

So I have an HTML file `a.html` and I have a JS file `b.js` with some API functions inside and a loop (explained shortly).

There is a common array `q`, defined as a `window` field inside of HTML (so it is accessible through `window.q`).

The API functions defined inside of `b.js` are used throughout `a.html` (for actions inside button tags, also inside script tags etc.), for example:

```
<script src="b.js" async></script>

<button onClick="onClick1()">1</button>
<button onClick="onClick2()">2</button>
<button onClick="onClick3()">3</button>
<button onClick="onClick4()">4</button>

<script>
function onClick1() {
  api_f1(...);
};
function onClick2() {
  api_f2(...);
};
function onClick3() {
  api_f3(...);
};
function onClick4() {
  api_f4(...);
};
</script>
```

What those API functions actually do, they push objects into that common array `q`, and `b.js` has a function called `execute()` which pulls out a first element of `q` (using `q.shift()`):

```
var execute = function() {

        var nextEvent = window.q.shift();

        //do something with nextEvent here

};
```

Now my question is,

How should I implement the loop inside `b.js` that will continuously call function `execute()` and retrieve the element from `q` or wait until there is an element if `q` is empty, without hogging the CPU?

I tried this:

```
while(1)
    {
        while(window.q.length==0)
        {}
        execute();
    }
```

but the page hangs,
Then I tried this:

```
while(1)
    {
        while(window.q.length==0)
              sleep();
        execute();
    }
```

This one was able to retrieve objects if I called API functions directly from `<script></script>` tags, but if I place them into button actions, the loop simply stops, while it was supposed to wait inside `while(window.crl8.q.length==0)` loop.

UPD. The loop in the second snippet stopped because there's no `sleep()` function defined. I replaced it with `await sleep(1000);` but the loop stops again without reaching `execute()` (no error this time)

Any ideas how I could implement this loop efficiently?

Comment: sleep? is this client side JavaScript? Normally use await or setTimeout

Comment: @mplungjan ah, right, that's why the loop stopped, I didn't check the exception value, I checked now and it says `Can't find variable: sleep`.

Comment: @mplungjan I replaced `sleep();` with `await sleep(1000);` and it stops again. It doesn't even reach `execute()`

Comment: Do you even have a function called sleep, because JS does not

Comment: @mplungjan it doesn't throw any exception when I use `await sleep(1000);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: @mplungjan yes, the combination of `async function` with `await` solved it, the loop executes now, thanks)